# What does "both" mean in <div style="clear:both">

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="float:left">Hello</div>
<div style="float:right">Howdy dere pardner</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

I get what it does, but why the name `both`?  What does `both` *mean*?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Both means "every item in a set of two things". The two things being "left" and "right"

Comment: Oh ok, so you can clear:right and left, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Because an element might follow an element that floats left which follows an element that floats right (for example) or the selector matches elements which follow things that float left and also matches elements which follow things that float right.

Comment: also If you only have elements floated `left`, you can just `clear:left`; rather than a redundant clear.

Comment: `clear:both` also has semantic meaning for every web developer out there. It means: I want the stuff after this to go in a "new row". And remember, at this level of programming `legibility > efficiency`

Answer (score 18):

Description of the possible values:

> - `left`: No floating elements allowed on the left side
> - `right`:    No floating elements allowed on the right side
> - `both`: No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side
> - `none`: Default. Allows floating elements on both sides
> - `inherit`: Specifies that the value of the clear property should be inherited from the parent element

Source: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Comment: If you copy content, you should at least quote it and it is good practice to mark your post as "community wiki", as the credit is not yours.

Comment: I would better use the official specification than W3Schools: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-clear

Answer (score 9):

Clear:both gives you that space between them.

For example your code:

```
  <div style="float:left">Hello</div>
  <div style="float:right">Howdy dere pardner</div>
```

Will currently display as :

```
Hello  ...................   Howdy dere pardner
```

If you add the following to above snippet,

```
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

In between them it will display as:

```
Hello ................ 
                       Howdy dere pardner
```

giving you that space between hello and Howdy dere pardner.

Js fiiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5vR/1/