# position: Sticky causes my div to double in size and overlay a previous div

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a sticky footer for a grid.

As soon as I add `position:sticky;` and `bottom:0px` to the footer, the footer doubles in size and overlays my the previous div (line in my grid)

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .fixed_header {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    .td,
    .th {
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      width: 100px;
      float: left;
    }

    .thead {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0px;
    }

    .th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .tr {
      display: block;
      clear: both;
      width: 500px;
    }

    .thead>div>div:nth-child(1) {
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
    }

    div.tbody>div.tr>div:nth-child(1) {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
    }

    div.tfooter {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      bottom:0px;
      background-color: green;
      /* width: 500px; */
    }
```

```html
<div class="myGrid">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">Col 1</div>
      <div class="th">Col 2</div>
      <div class="th">Col 3</div>
      <div class="th">Col 4</div>
      <div class="th">Col 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 1-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 2-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-4</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="tfooter">
    this is my footer
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason that I don't understand the tfooter needed `clear:both` for the problem to be solved.

Comment: Well done for finding it. I was trying to solve your problem and could not find the reason why did it behaved like that. But, if I may suggest, I would advise you to use table for this. Or if not table, then, use flexbox since it will offer you a way out of all the floating hell (that caused your problem) and it will be a step towards responsive layout.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299965/what-does-both-mean-in-div-style-clearboth

Comment: @LazarNikolic - yep - I'm looking at several approaches toward creating a data-grid - I wanted to try divs, but yep, it's really not fun :)